# Why Are These CGAL Bin/Lib vc140 Not vc141?

Tags: cgal

I have successfully built the latest CGAL v4.11 with Visual Studio Enterprise 2017 on Windows 10 64-bit. Everything is working well, but I just wonder why the libs are named with vc140 not vc141? My boost is v1.65.1 MSVC 14.1, MSVC platform toolset v141. Is there anything wrong or could anyone please explain it?

Edit: Here are the libs

```
CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-4.11.dll
CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.dll
CGAL_Core-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.pdb
CGAL_ImageIO-vc140-mt-4.11.dll
CGAL_ImageIO-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.dll
CGAL_ImageIO-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.pdb
CGAL_Qt5-vc140-mt-4.11.dll
CGAL_Qt5-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.dll
CGAL_Qt5-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.pdb
CGAL-vc140-mt-4.11.dll
CGAL-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.dll
CGAL-vc140-mt-gd-4.11.pdb
Debug
Release
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CGAL cmake machinery does not handle the minor version number of MSVC compilers for naming the libraries (which is why you have 140 and not 141).

See [this file](https://github.com/sloriot/cgal/blob/master/Installation/cmake/modules/CGAL_GeneratorSpecificSettings.cmake).

Comment: Thank you so much for that!